null value in column "status" violates not-null constraint
I am trying to use ONE method for partial updates.
For example: I one request I want to update 'status' field in another request I want to update 'is_online' and 'rq_id' fields
My code
# schemas/tasks.py

from pydantic import BaseModel

class UpdateTask(BaseModel):
    id: str
    rq_id: Optional[str] = None
    priority: Optional[int] = None
    status: Optional[Status] = None
    status_update_time: Optional[datetime] = None
    has_files: Optional[bool] = None
    is_online: Optional[bool] = None


# main.py
@app.post("/tasks/update")
def get_tasks(task_data: UpdateTask, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    task = db.query(Task).filter_by(id=task_data.id).one_or_none()
    if task:
        for key, val in dict(task_data).items():
            setattr(task, key, val)
        db.commit()

        return task
    raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Not found")

For request
{
  "id": "3",
  "rq_id": "string",
  "priority": 1234

}

I have an error:

sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "status" violates not-null constraint
51_fetcher_new-consumer-1   | DETAIL:  Failing row contains (3, string, 1234, null, 2024-12-16 09:06:22, null, null, null, {"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}).


Reason -- unset fields set to None, what is the proper way to eliminate inset fields from update? (I understand that i can check if is None but is there better way?

I think you can use exclude_unset or exclude_none. Please find more detailed information here
